# Mysql Data type for amount of time remaining in a game

Tags: mysql

i am working on a app that is keeping track of high school sporting even scores.

it will allow users to submit scores of games in progress. right now i have a database table called scores.

But i am stuck when it comes to representing the amount of time in minutes and seconds left in the game.

Comment: Instead of recording the (relative) "time left" consider reporting the "time submitted" as well as the "end time". Then the "time left" is just the difference of the other two (absolute) times.

Comment: i am capturing the timestamp of when the score was submitted by the user. although there is really no way of capturing the end time since its "game time" and you have stoppages of play or the stoppages of the game clock due to timeouts, an incomplete pass, or the ball carrier going out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [TIME type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html):

> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or 'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. The hours part may be so large because the TIME type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).

Comment: that seemed like the obvious answer, but i was not sure since i was not representing a time of day, but an elapsed or remaining time. thank you.